# Is it possible to compute homology groups of a space given the Pontryagin ring?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Or similarly, given the cohomology ring of a space, is it possible to compute its cohomology groups? I'm mainly interested in integer and mod 2 homology and cohomology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the Pontryagin ring $H_*(X ; \mathbb{Z})$ of the $H$-space $X$, then you automatically know $H_n(X; \mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$ as $H_n(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is merely the $n$th graded component of $H_*(X;\mathbb{Z})$. Then you can use Universal Coefficients to determine $H_n(X; A)$ for any abelian group $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)